# Building button in jQuery through function-paramater usage

Tags: javascript, jquery, button, parameters

Good morning! I am trying to create a function to generate a set of buttons on a webpage using jQuery. My sample code is below. The buttons are created (yay) but the parameters for value, onclick etc. are not used (boo). Please can someone with better skills that me show me the error in my code? Thanks so much for your help! I am beating my head against a wall here...

```
var buttonBar = document.getElementById("ButtonBar");
function genButton (butName, butLabel, action) {
    $('#buttonBar').append
        ('<input type="button" 
        name=butName 
        value = butLabel 
        onclick = action>');
}

genButton('butAsIs', 'Buy As Is', 'funAsIs()');

function funAsIs() {
    window.alert("Buy Me Pressed"); //TestCode 001
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With your code you append just strings as parameters, not your variables. 
For correct work, you may write

```
$('#buttonBar').append
    ('<input type="button" name="' + butName + '" value ="' + butLabel  + '" onclick="' + action + '">');
```

Or use es6 syntax with `${expressions}`

Answer (score 0):

The butName, butLabel and Action are taken as string and not as interpolated variables inside your code. Here is a working examaple of your `code :`

https://jsfiddle.net/qtjtbsz6/

Answer (score 0):

To create new input you should use `document.createElement("input");`.

```
  // Let's create an input 
  var element = document.createElement("input");
```

Assigning new attributes are really easy in this way

```
  element.type = 'button';
  element.value = butLabel; 
  element.name = butName;
```

Adding onclick event is a bit tricky. We need to wrap it inside function then we can invoke it.

```
  element.onclick = function() { 
    action(actionParams); 
  };
```

---

To generate new button we will use:

```
function generateButton(butName, butLabel, action, actionParams) { ... }
```

we can call this function for example like this:

```
generateButton('yourName', 'yourLabel', popAlert, { alertText: 'hello!', randomStuff: 'random' })
```

`action` is a function name that we pass as an argument. Remember now to add `()` - important part here.

`actionParams` are our `action` arguments. In our case it is just javascript object `{ alertText: 'hello!', randomStuff: 'random' }`, you can pass anything you want.

Finally we append new input to our `#result` selector.

Here is working example. Run code snippet to see how it works.

```js
function generateButton(butName, butLabel, action, actionParams) {
  // Let's create an input 
  var element = document.createElement("input");
  
  // Now we assign
  element.type = 'button';
  element.value = butLabel; 
  element.name = butName; 
  element.onclick = function() { 
    action(actionParams); 
  };

  // Now we append
  var result = document.getElementById("result");
  result.appendChild(element);
}

function popAlert(params) {
  alert(params.alertText);
  console.log(params.randomStuff);
}
```

```css
#result {
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #eee;
}

input[type="button"] {
  margin: 2px;
}
```

```html
<input type="button" value="click me to generate new button!" onclick="generateButton('yourName', 'yourLabel', popAlert, { alertText: 'hello!', randomStuff: 'random' })" />

<div id="result"></div>
```